# Print a formatted POST request URL using Python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a remote API I hit with POST requests. I have two scripts that do this job. One works; the other I need to debug.

The one that works is more complex and in Python, using the `requests` package:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r = requests.post("http://thing.com/", 
                  data = {"param1": "foo"},
                  auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user@domain.com", "password"))
```

This works great. The other script, which is CLI, does theoretically the identical freaking thing and does not work. The CLI script prints out the URL it's trying to use. I'd love to get the working Python script to tell me which the hell URL *it* is trying to use. How do I make `requests` tell me the fully formatted URL it's using?

Comment: What does `r.url` show? And not seen `querydata=` before - is that meant to be `data=`?

Comment: ACK. Yes. I'll fix that -- the script uses the `data` parameter, `querydata` is a typo. And I've tried r.url -- it prints `http://thing.com/` and nothing else.

Comment: Well in that case - what's your command line script? Is it using curl or something? You've checked it is using POST and to the same URL and is properly auth'ing?

Comment: The script uses [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie). It auths correctly, and the base URL is the same as the base URL output by `r.url`. Instead of returning the correct response, it returns "No post data submitted" -- so I was hoping to look at how `requests` is formatting its POST data.

Comment: So you're running: `http post http://thing.com param1=foo -a user@domain.com:password` ?

Comment: To be clear, @Gastove, `http://thing.com/` *is* the full url. Unlike `GET`, `POST` carries no data in its URL. If there the CLI version prints a different URL, then there is something you aren't showing us.

Comment: Oh.... I meant `http -f post` - as httpie will use json by default, so you have to tell it to use form encoded data

Comment: @Robᵩ -- ah, I did not know that! httpie has been outputting something along the lines of `POST thing.com/?param1=foo`, and I assumed that was correct. It probably means I'm actually Doing It Wrong.

Comment: @JonClements -- yeah, following up on what Rob said, I've had `http post http://thing.com param1==foo -a etc` -- which is the wrong operator, I think. And it turns out to have also been a -f problem -- did not realize the API I'm using requires form-encoded data.

Comment: Yep. That fixed it. `http POST http://thing.com/ param1=foo -f -a` works far, far better. Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to print out debug info about all your requests:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

You'll get output like

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <URL>
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

If you want to print other information, you can print out the objects you're passing in or implement some of the requests [event hooks](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=hooks#event-hooks).